# Remove duplicated row from 2 tables in different database

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-data-integration

I have 2 users table in different databases and I would like to get only unique rows from one those tables.

On the following example, I need the list of emails which have no duplicate name.

I am using Pentaho DI Kettle.

**Table Users from database 1**

```
ID  | Name        | Email
--- | ----------- | -------------
1   | Jonh Snow   | jonhs@got.com  
--- | ----------- | -------------
2   | Sansa Stark | sansas@got.com  
--- | ----------- | -------------
3   | Ayra Stark  | ayras@got.com
```

**Table Users from database 2**

```
ID  | Name        | Email
--- | ----------- | -------------
1   | Jonh Stott  | jonhs@example.com  
--- | ----------- | -------------
2   | Jonh Jonh   | jonhj@example.com  
--- | ----------- | -------------
3   | Ayra Stark  | ayras@got.com
```

**Desired Result**

```
ID  | Name        | Email
--- | ----------- | -------------
1   | Jonh Snow   | jonhs@got.com  
--- | ----------- | -------------
2   | Sansa Stark | sansas@got.com
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you need to keep only the emails which are not duplicates in DB1 union DB2?

Well, follow your logic: get the data in (with one `Input table` by DB connection), count the number of records per emails (`Memory Group by`) and `Filter` out the emails with a count greater than 1.

Use the `Memory Group by`, which do not requires sorting. In the `Group field` put the key: `email`. And in the `Aggregates` put the `Number of rows` (in the Type drop down), and the `First Value` (or `Last Value`) of `Name` otherwise this column will disappear from the stream.

And `Add a sequence` if you need to create the ID on the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform an UNION ALL ( simply join the two files to an dummy)
2. Perform an Sort on email.
3. use UNIQUE rows on Name.
4. use a stream lookup on Name having one input as table1 and second unique rows.
5. Filter rows on id < 3 and id isnull.